# How to calculate superTrend in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, indicator

I'm trying to calculate supertrend based on this moving average code.

But not be able to get exact value like superTrend. Here is the basic code which I was using. The first one is EMA, it's is working perfectly but not be able to calculate superTrend like this.

```
import 'dart:ui';
import '../../models/candle.dart';
import '../../models/indicator.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class EMA extends Indicator {
  EMA({
    required int period,
    required Color color,
  }) : super(
          name: "EMA $period",
          dependsOnNPrevCandles: period,
          calculator: (int index, List<Candle> candles) {
            double multiplier = (2 / (period + 1));
            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < period; i++) {
              sum += candles[i + index].close;
            }
            double ema = sum / period; //(summ.close / period);
            ema = multiplier * (candles[index].close - ema) + ema;
            return [ema];
          },
          indicatorComponentsStyles: [
            IndicatorStyle(
                name: "EMA $period", color: color),
          ],
        );
}
```

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../models/candle.dart';
import '../../models/indicator.dart';

class SupertrendIndicator extends Indicator {
  SupertrendIndicator(
      {required int length, required double multiplier, required Color color})
      : super(
            name: "Supertrend $length/$multiplier",
            dependsOnNPrevCandles: length + 1,
            calculator: (index, candles) {
               final candle = candles[index];

              // Calculate basic upper and lower bands
              final basicUpper = (candle.high + candle.low) / 2 +
                  multiplier * _atr(candles, index, length);
              final basicLower = (candle.high + candle.low) / 2 -
                  multiplier * _atr(candles, index, length);

              // Calculate final upper and lower bands
              final finalUpper = basicUpper;
              final finalLower = basicLower;

              // Calculate Supertrend value
              final supertrend = candle.close > basicUpper
                  ? finalUpper
                  : candle.close < basicLower
                      ? finalLower
                      : previousSupertrend > previousBasicUpper
                          ? basicLower
                          : basicUpper;
              return [
                supertrend,
              ];
            },
            indicatorComponentsStyles: [
              IndicatorStyle(name: "Supertrend", color: color),
            ]);

  static double _atr(List<Candle> candles, int index, int length) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      final trueRange1 = math.max(
        candles[i].high - candles[i].low,
        (i > 0 ? candles[i].high - candles[i - 1].close : 0),
      );
      final trueRange2 = math.max(
        trueRange1,
        (i > 0 ? candles[i - 1].close - candles[i].low : 0),
      );
      sum += trueRange2;
    }
    return sum / length;
  }
}
```